# How to get random elements from a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an 2 dimensional array and the number of elements in each row is different. How i can get random elements from this array? Does anyone have a best solution?

```
arr = [
 [2,3,4],
 [3,4]
 [1,22,3,45]
]
```

Comment: What language are you actually using?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the input array and get the random element.

```js
const arr = [
 [2,3,4],
 [3,4],
 [1,22,3,45]
];

const flattenArr = arr.flat();

const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*flattenArr.length);
console.log(flattenArr[randomIndex]);
```

Comment: `flat` mathod is also a part of array in js. I didn't know that. Learned something new 

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
  [2, 3, 4],
  [3, 4],
  [1, 22, 3, 45],
];
const flatArray = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return [...acc, ...curr];
}, []);

function getRandomNumber(len) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
}

const randomNumber = getRandomNumber(flatArray.length);
console.log(flatArray[randomNumber]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random index between 0 and the nested array length, try this:

```js
let arr = [
 [2,3,4],
 [3,4],
 [1,22,3,45]
]


let result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  result.push(arr[i][Math.floor(Math.random() * arr[i].length + 0)]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var arr = [
 [2,3,4],
 [3,4],
 [1,22,3,45]
]

flatArr=arr.flatMap(x=>x)

console.log(flatArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * flatArr.length)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Math.random() to generate integers between 0 (inclusive) and length of sub array (exclusive).

```js
const numbers = [
  [2, 3, 4],
  [3, 4],
  [1, 22, 3, 45],
];

const result = numbers.map(
  (_, i, arr) => arr[i][~~(Math.random() * arr[i].length)]
);

console.log(result);
```